# xubuntu with rasberry pi 4 WiFi Networks device not ready

Tags: networking, wireless, raspberrypi

I have following issue on the dropp down menu on the nettwork icon it stands WiFi nettwork device not ready.

When the raspberry pi try to search for wifi connections it spins for ever.

Any suggestion to my problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)